# How should I solve this Logarithmic equation analytically?

Tags: equation-solving

Is there any way to solve the following equation analytically?

```
eq = 
  (2 + 16 P π r^2 + 8 r^2 β^2 (1 - Sqrt[1 + q^2/(r^4 β^2)] + 
  Log[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 + q^2/(r^4 β^2)])]))/(8 π r) == T;
Solve[eq, r]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

Comment: I thing that is very, very unlikely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve a complex equation symbolically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193380/solve-a-complex-equation-symbolically)

Comment: @morbo Unfortunately no. What suggested there is to solve the equation numerically by FindRoot. But I need the analytic answer.

Comment: @SoodehZ. You’re stuck by doing it by hand then...:( though you can try using ‘reduce’ with boundaries on all of your variables...it still probably won’t find a solution.

Comment: @morbo. I think you are right. I should do it by hand. (Also I'll try reduce with boundaries. May be it works.). Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered reducing the number of variables? Nondimensionalize it, in a way, to have an easier time solving it?